# My domain has 302 redirection, i want to know the method that used to redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Basically I want to put a `301` from `namilaauto.com` to `carauction.lk`.

I placed the `301` redirection code in `.htaccess` file and checked, the browser showing a error that **This Webpage has a redirect loop** that mean there are too many redirects. Currently there is a `302` redirection. 
Now I want to remove that first.

I couldn't find the method that used to `302` redirection currently. I checked `.htaccess` file , `http`, `php` and `java` file there is no redirection using these methods.

Now my question is how can I find the method that used to `302` redirect?

Comment: Maybe your code checking domain in somewhere. Find `namilaauto.com` in your code at `carauction.lk`. If not found find in your database.

Comment: currently its redirecting to namilaauto so i cant find anything on carauction. but i find carauction in namilaauto index page, there is no such redirection code inside. how can i find in database

Comment: your website are using a CMS or build from a framework?

Comment: its build with php framework

Comment: Try to `die` on top of your index file. if redirect 302 not fire, It mean you have a redirect somewhere in your code. Otherwise error from your htacess file.

Comment: this is how htaccess look like [link](http://prntscr.com/80nhaj) @NgôVănThao did notice any error in my htaccess file

Comment: I just visited namilaauto.com and it doesn't have a redirect loop, so I guess you fixed it. What was the problem?

Comment: ya its fine now. i think the client made some think on domain registry. have you got any idea that can we put redirection using domain registrar like godaddy